# How do I open XLS files in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

I've just bought Numbers and I'm trying to open some XLS files.  They're in Excel '97 format, not encrypted, and with no password set.  However, when I try to open them, I get this error message:

```
"The document is encrypted and can't be opened"
```

They open fine in openoffice.  How do I open them in Numbers?

Comment: Are you sure that the file isn't corrupted? Can you regenerate or get it from source again?

Comment: Did you try to same them from OpenOffice into .xls again and then open them in Numbers?

Comment: @Robin - yes, I'm sure there's nothing wrong with the files.

Comment: @Patrix - yes. I've even tried saving as an ODS, then opening that ODS and re-saving as an XLS. Still no good.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes a xls file don't have password to open it, but it has it to avoid modifying certain fields, you can validate that. 
Also, if you have access to a PC with Windows you can try to save your xls file in a newer format.

Another alternative is to use a program like parallels or VMware to install/emulate window on your Mac.

Comment: I think you're right about it having a protected field.  However I don't have access to Windows or a newer version of Excel - I need to make this work in Numbers.

Comment: If the xls has a protected field, then Numbers wont open the file and it would show the "The document is encrypted and can't be opened" message. Don't know if there is a hack or something like that, but I read on an Apple forum about this constrain.

Comment: OK - where do I file a bug? That's a stupid error message if the problem is that Numbers doesn't support encrypted fields